# Is google maps static api free?

Tags: google-maps, google

I'd like to write an app which uses google maps (via javascript library like gmaps.js). 
I'll GET the GPS positions from my server and I'll use google maps+js library to draw them on map. 
I don't need to use any api-keys.

Is it free and unlimited or even for commercial usage?

Answer (score 3):

Google Static Maps API Usage Limits

> Most websites and applications may use the Google Static Maps API free
>   of charge. However, if you consistently generate a high amount of
>   traffic, usage limits apply and you will need to pay for extra usage.
>   If your site or application generates 25 000 Static Maps image
>   requests or more each day, for more than 90 consecutive days, we'll
>   attempt to get in touch with you to talk about payment. Don't worry,
>   if you go over the limits, we won't immediately shut off your API
>   access or display error messages on your site.

If you think your website or application will generate high Static Maps image requests consistently in the long term, you should consider one of the following options:

**Modify your application so that your usage is less than 25 000 Static Maps image requests per day.**

Enroll for automated billing of excess image requests in the Google APIs Console. Additional image requests can be purchased at the rate currently listed in the FAQ.

Purchase a Google Maps API for Work license.
You can buy Google Maps Enterprise here:
https://www.google.com/a/signup/?enterprise_product=GOOGLE.MAPSENGINEPRO_STANDALONE&hl=en#0

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits